# Unit test on generic function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, xunit

I create the new generic function as below

```
public T ErrorHandling<T>(HttpRequestException exception) where T : IWebResponse, new() {
    if (exception == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) {
          logger.LogError(exception);
    }
    return new T {
        ErrorMessage = exception.Message
    };
}
```

I want to make a XUnit test here, but not a idea for this. I know one of way is create the dummy class to do, is that other way to do ?

Thank you

Comment: Why not create a dummy class?

Comment: Quite unclear what "other" ways you expect to exist. There is no way to execute function without passing all parameters and generic type parameter is just another parameter (even in pure functional languages, definitely not in C#). Some [edit] that clarify what you are trying to avoid or how roughly desired code looks like could help.